# Hide Wordpress widgets on a mobile device

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, version

I'm having trouble with ads - I've placed them in widgets and now the [mobile version](http://nix-pix.co.uk) of the site sucks - the ads are too big for a phone and ruin the theme. What I came up with right now is this:

`.mobile #widget{
display: none;
}`

But the thing is, the `#widget` doesn't work and I don't know how if it's possible to get rid of widgets like that. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Show more code please or an URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you wrote doesn't really make much sense because you're writing your CSS as if this scenario existed:

```
<div class="mobile">
    <div id="widget">your ad</div>
</div>
```

This obviously does not exist.

You can see here how the theme targets mobile devices with @media queries from the CSS file located on your site:

http://nix-pix.co.uk/wp-content/themes/alyeska/assets/css/responsive.css

So, it's actually pretty simple -- Any custom styles you want to target mobile would simply be placed inside a @media query like this:

```
@media(max-width:480px){
    /* All styles for mobile devices go here. */
}
```

What that basically says in plain English is: "IF the device's viewport is 480px or less, include this CSS" -- This is quickly becoming one of the most modern and popular ways to target mobile devices because there are now so many out there. Many believe it's sort of backwards thinking to try use javascript or the user agents with PHP to specifically target the iPhone or the Android phone, etc. These methods definitely have their purpose, but not really for things that are this simple, in my opinion. Instead, we use CSS @media queries to target different device widths.

Ok, so now you want to hide where you have that Ad area towards the bottom of the content. Upon inspecting it with a tool like Firebug or Google Chrome's web developer tools, we can quickly see it's wrapped in a class called "main-bottom" --

[image: In this screenshot, I'm using Firebug, an extension for Firefox.]

Since we know in CSS when you're referring to a class we prefix it with a period, and to hide an element we can use the [display](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) property, we'd just now put this into our @media query.

```
@media(max-width:480px){
    .main-bottom {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks much! Also, is there any way of actually getting rid of the sidebars for the mobile version,because I have very big skyscraper ads, and they take up _much_ of the space on the site! Thanks!

Comment: See if you can figure it out with the explanation I added above.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing any code or a URL, it's impossible to tell you what CSS you should use. However, my advice would be to not use CSS at all, and simply not write the sidebar to the page if the user is on a mobile device.

I don't know what you're using to detect mobile devices, but this is what I've used in the past. Not ideal, but it's done the job in a pinch.

In functions.php, add:

```
function mobile_detected($agents)
{
    $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    foreach($agents as $agent)
    {
        if(strpos($userAgent,strtolower($agent)) !== false)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And in your theme where you're calling your sidebar:

```
<?php
$devices = array(
"iphone", "ipod", "ipad",
"android", "windows ce", "windows phone os",
"blackberry", "palm", "symbian", "series60"
);
if(!mobile_detected($devices))
    dynamic_sidebar('Your Sidebar');
?>
```

Comment: what do I put instead of 'Your Sidebar'?

Comment: Whatever the name of your sidebar is. I don't know what that would be since I don't know how you or the theme developer registered your sidebars.

Comment: The idea here is that you would place this code in your theme. The second part of this code would be placed wherever your Sidebar Call is happening. Look for something along the lines of "dynamic_sidebar('Right Sidebar')". That is what's loading your sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using `Widget Options Plugin` which you can hide widgets on mobile and other devices. It's free on the repository : https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-options/ . You can check the screenshot below. Thanks!

[image]